# Why is zero being returned by this function?

Tags: c

When I input a duration of `2.75` this function returns `'and 0 minute(s)'` when I need `'and 45 minute(s)'` returned. The problem is in the `else` `if` part.

```
void duration_time_min(double duration)
{
  int duration_min;

  if (duration < 1)
  {
    duration_min = duration * 60; // decimal times 60 converted to int
    printf("Trip duration: 0 hour(s) and %i minute(s)\n", duration_min);
  }
  else if (duration > 1)
  {
    duration_min = (int) duration; // cast double to int
    duration_min = duration_min - duration; // get decimal value for min
    duration_min = duration_min * 60;
    printf("and %i minute(s)\n", duration_min);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. If you do not have a debugger or do not know how to use it yet, then insert `printf` statements printing `duration_min` after each assignment. Then you will see where the error occurs.

Comment: Take a closer look here: `duration_min = duration_min - duration`. Consider the data type of `duration_min`.

Comment: You've mixed up your ints and floats.

Comment: This probably because when you subtract double from integer, the double value gets implicitly casted to int thus loosing the decimal part. So 2 - 2 becomes 0. You should explicitly cast to double to keep the decimal or, better yet, just do all decimal computation in doubles and convert to int, if necessary in the end.

Comment: Think also about what happens if `duration` happens to be exactly 1.

Comment: @VictorHavin: When `double` is subtracted from `int`, the `int` is converted to `double`. In the OP’s code, however, the result, which is a `double` with value −.75, is assigned to an `int`, so it is converted to an `int`.

Comment: You are right. I meant to say the result is casted to int. The way I put it could make an impression that operand is casted to int. My point is: when you mix ints and doubles in one expression you can run into problems. You should either multiply everything by 10^n wher n is the number of decimal places you want to keep or, better yet, use doubles across the board. Doubles are cheap these days.

Comment: To be clear: Your function is `void` and does not return anything.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the line

```
duration_min = duration_min - duration; // get decimal value for min
```

You end up making `duration_min` zero in that line since it is of type `int`. It cannot capture anything after the decimal point.

Also, the logic is incorrect. You need to use `duration - duration_min`.

Use a floating point to capture the difference.

```
double temp = duration - duration_min;
duration_min = temp * 60;
```

Also, don't expect the output to be exact since floating point representation is not always exact.

Answer (score 1):

when you pass duration = 2.75 something following is happening

it goes into else if part as expected

```
duration_min = (int) duration; // duration_min=2;duration=2.75
duration_min = duration_min - duration; /* value for (duration_min - duration) = -0.75 
                                         but duration_min is int it will be converted to 0; 
                                         so after this statement execute 
                                         duration_min = 0 */
duration_min = duration_min * 60; //duration_min = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your program on this line :

```
duration_min = duration_min - duration;
```

Since your duration_min is 2, this line makes duration_min = 2-2.75 = 0.
To fix this, your line needs be :

```
duration_min = duration-duration_min;
```

But now another problem appears : we are trying to store a decimal value inside a integer. To fix this too, we have 2 ways : change the type of duration_min to double (and change multiple other things) OR just multiply by 60 on the same line.
If we go with the secound option, the line will look like this :

```
duration_min = (duration-duration_min)* 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing program under debugger and stepping through, would help you understand the problem:

```
 // duration=2.75
 duration_min = (int) duration;
 // duration_min = 2

 // now:        duration_min - duration = 2 - 2.75 = -0.75
 // but 0.75 has to be converted to int value 
 // (int) 0.75 = 0 
 duration_min = duration_min - duration; // get decimal value for min
 // so  `duration_min` = 0
```

Be careful when you mix `double` and `int` values.  When `double` is converted to `int` it is always truncated.

Your program also has another problem. It does not print anything for duration = 1 hour.

Take a look at the possible solution. Keep separate `int` value for hours and a `double` for minutes. Then you have a clear separation between those two.
It makes calculations more obvious.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void duration_time_min(double duration)
{
    double duration_min;
    int hours;

   if(duration == 1.0)
   {
       printf("Trip duration: 1 hour\n");
       return;
   }

   if (duration < 1.0)   //  duration less then hour
   {
        duration_min = duration * 60.0; 
        printf("Trip duration: 0 hours and %.1f minute(s)\n", duration_min);
        return;
   }

    // (duration > 1.0) // more than hour

    hours = (int) duration;              // cast double to int, get hours
    duration_min = duration - hours;     // get fraction part for the minutes
    duration_min = duration_min * 60.0;  // calculate minutes

    printf("Trip duration: %d hours and %.1f minute(s)\n", hours, duration_min);
 }

int main(void)
{
    duration_time_min(1.0);
    duration_time_min(0.75);
    duration_time_min(2.75);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Trip duration: 1 hour
Trip duration: 0 hours and 45.0 minute(s)
Trip duration: 2 hours and 45.0 minute(s)
```